# Can you do conditional formatting with AngularJS?

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an element containing a value from my controller:

```
<span>[[myvalue]]</span>
```

which I'd change the background color depending on the value. For example values 1-5 should have red and 6-10 should have green.

```
<span style='background-color: #green'>9</span>
<span style='background-color: #red'>1</span>
```

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As tymeJV mentioned with `ngStyle` you can also use `ngClass`

```
<span ng-class="{'myClass' : (myValue < 9)}">{{myValue}}</span>
```

Also to promote some unit testing I would also recommend placing tho logic into a function so you can test easily as it also makes the markup a bit easier to read.

Markup

```
<span ng-class="{'myClass' : isSpecial(myValue)}">{{myValue}}</span>
```

Controller

```
$scope.isSpecial = function(value){ return myValue < 9};
```

Granted my example and yours is a bit contrived, but can help make things easier to maintain later on.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example using `ngStyle`

```
<span  ng-style="myStyle(myValue)"> {{myValue}} </span>
```

controller:

```
$scope.myStyle= function(value){
    return parseInt(value) > 5 ? {color: 'green'} : {color: 'red'}
}
```